# Tascam DR-40 & Shure SM58

Tags: portable-recorder, tascam, microphone

I have a two Shure SM58 which I use for stage work. I also have just acquired a Tascam Dr40, primarily for the xlr inputs. I am getting a mono signal from the SM58s and no one from where I bought the unit and no one from Tascam, where I left an enquiry is able to tell me whether that means I have a faulty unit or a mono signal is what you get with the unit. I have been through the unit's recording menu and the mono signal comes when the unit is set to stereo, the two mics plugged in produce two separate mono signals too.

Does anyone here have a unit and mics and knows what the answer is please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the sm8 is a mono mic so:
1 sm58 mic = mono signal --> mono mic
2 sm58 mics = 2 mono signals --> you can set them up for stereo micing(xy,ab etc.) or record two different sources in mono without spatializing

inputs + internal mic --> combination of above + 1 stereo track combined of the tr40 internal mics channels = tascam 4 track recorder

Or did i get the question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand the question correctly, what you're saying is this:

• You have two separate Shure SM-58 microphones plugged into inputs 1 and 2 on the DR-40;
• When you wear headphones and monitor your recording, you're getting a uniform sound in each ear, ie. a mono signal?

Sorry to answer your question with a question, but... is this 'mono' signal derived from one of the microphones only, or both?  If the former, the inaudible microphone is either faulty or is connected with a faulty lead.  If the latter, you might need to check the DR-40's mixer settings.  It's possible to pan both external inputs to the centre in monitor output.  If I remember accurately though, they'll still record to separate tracks.  (You should try recording too, and see what you come up with.)